# What is the Trustor?

Tags: stellar-sdk

I am struggling with the Terminolgy.

```
allowTrust := txnbuild.SetTrustLineFlags{
        Trustor:  Whos Address?,
        Asset:    issuedAsset,
        SetFlags: []txnbuild.TrustLineFlag{txnbuild.TrustLineAuthorized},
    }
```

Who's address do we place at the Trustor? Is it the Account that wants to trust a token? Or is it the Token Issuers Address?
I find this confusing because the issuedAsset is a json object that includes the address of the Token issuer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Trustor is the account which is authorized.
This operation is called by the asset issuer to authorized an account to add the trustline for example.
[API doc: AllowTrust](https://developers.stellar.org/api/resources/operations/object/allow-trust/)

If you want to add a trustline to your account, the operation to use is ChangeTrust. [API doc: ChangeTrust](https://developers.stellar.org/api/resources/operations/object/change-trust/)